# HTML & CSS: Split page horizontally with vertical scrollbars after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<div class="upper">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>
    <p>1</p>

    <input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
</div>

<div id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;" class="lower" > WELCOME
   <p>toty</p>
</div>
```

i want to display a split when button is clicked

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a [on topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and how to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sir please refer to my example here http://jsfiddle.net/8xr0oy7L/ please help me am so stuck as am new to stack overflow please please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kn8spftx/)

HTML

```
<div id="upper-section">

        <p>1</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>1</p>        
      <input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" />
</div>
<div class="lower" id="welcomeDiv"  style="display:none;"></div>
```

JS

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('upper-section').classList.add("upper");
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: it something like this but i want the button to be in the upper div so that when i click it the down div should show...

Comment: thank you !!! have made some modification and the output is now okay for me...